# Washington Gas Light Company serial preferred stock $5.00 series

Tags: united-states, historical-data, preferred-stocks

Where can I find the historical price of this preferred stock, especially for May 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Accordington to [Quantum Online](https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=WGLCP*&sopt=symbol), **Washington Gas Light $5.00 Series Cumul Preferred** stock was called on 12/20/2019 and is no longer trading.

Comment: Yes, the stock was called 12/20/19. I'm trying to find the historical price on the issue date, 5/9/1980. This is likely the original cost basis.

Comment: I would assume that since it's a $100 preferred then that was the par price at issue.  But to be sure, go to the WGL web site and contact them.  Ask if they can provide the  answer or in lieu of that, a link to the prospectus.  Contact Quantum Online as well through **Feedback** and see if they have a link.  They usually provide one with active issues.  Perhaps it still exists for a called issue. You might want to edit the question to reflect the date properly.

Comment: I too assumed $100. Just looking for hard confirmation. Thanks.